# Find all active AD users in specified period

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need some help with finding all active AD Users. The task is to find all users, that had been active for 8 months. So far, I managed to find all users that are active right now, but I need the specific period. Here's my Powershell code:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADUser  -Filter 'enabled -eq $true'  -Properties CN |
 Select-Object @{Label='ParentContainer';Expression={$_.Distinguishedname -replace "CN=$($_.cn),"}} |
 Group-Object -Property ParentContainer |
 Select-Object Name,Count
 | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users2.txt
```

Thx in advance

Comment: You could use their lastlogon as reference

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you need to know when the user has been disabled to find its history and find out the active users within a period
for example, if the users disable before last month that means it was active last month
this link will show that
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2560e797-a929-4fe0-bfcb-8e7d850d865b/ad-users-disabled-date

Comment: Well I actually need all users that have been active for 8 months straight and have not been disabled in this period. The disabled users are of no importance in this case.